# Open pycharm for multiple projects with different environment variables

Tags: pycharm, subprocess

As you know, Pycharm can not be opened with mutiple instances (I know there's a way with `idea.properties` but I want to do something automatically), so when you open a new project window, it will inherit environment variables from current window(I mean **system env-vars** or **os.environ**, not anything manually set in UI for a project).

Example:

Open a project, go to Terminal, run `set PYTHONPATH=whatever_path`. Then open another project in new window, and go to its Terminal, run `set PTYHONPATH`, and you can see the result is `whatever_path` that you set in the previous window.

This is bad because `subprocess` with `env` argument only works for the first time, if there's an existing Pycharm instance opened, then passing environment variables into `subprocess` takes no effect.

Does anyone have idea to get rid of it?

Comment: What is the original issue? Why do you need to start PyCharm with different system env?

Comment: because PyCharm can automatically set Python Interpreter from PATH and Interpreter Paths from PYTHONPATH, so if I correctly set the env before open PyCharm, I can do development in a correct env with all dependencies and auto-complete and without any virtualenv thing. I don't want to use virtualenv because we'll use [Rez](https://github.com/nerdvegas/rez/) instead.